# Test Users for a Production App

Tags: facebook

We have developed a Facebook Canvas App, and using the test version, we create test users who can successfully install and test the app.

Here's the thing.  Using the production version of the app (not yet approved by Facebook), and using test users created under this version, when I try and install the app to the user I get the error message "User is not allowed to see the application.: The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration."

I have made sure I am not logged in as another test user, I've cleared the cache prior to logging in as the test user, etc.

As near as I can tell, test users created under the production version should be able install the app and test it, correct?

If not, then when you submit the app for Facebook Approval, what accounts will the use?

Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, test users should be able to login to the app. File a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation:

Created test users under the test app won't be able to use the prod app, just as Created test users under the prod app won't be able to use the test app. 
Real users, added as TESTERS of the prod app, should be added manually as testers of the Test App.

Comment: The thing is that I created the Test Users under the Prod App.  I even deleted at Test Users created under the Test App to ensure no bleed-over.  I am still baffled.

Comment: If the test user from the test app doesn't work with the test app, I would definitely file a bug under developers.facebook.com/bugs with good reproduction steps. Include App Id, ID of the test user, and Graph API call you're making so that it gets taken care of fast!